# Time Error creating anything in powershell of azure

Tags: azure, runtime-error

New-AzPublicIpAddress: The access token expiry UTC time '10/21/2020 3:45:35 AM' is earlier than current UTC time '10/21/2020 4:07:27 AM'.
StatusCode: 401
ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized
ErrorCode: ExpiredAuthenticationToken
ErrorMessage: The access token expiry UTC time '10/21/2020 3:45:35 AM' is earlier than current UTC time '10/21/2020 4:07:27 AM'.
OperationID : 98fe3438-abb2-4b7e-8e69-bb25d29f4883

Comment: Please provide more context: Which installation instructions did you follow to install azure powershell? How did you setup your access to azure? Are you just working from your normal computer or are you running in some docker-container or virtual machine or something like this? What time does a powershell command like "get-date" display? Does the problem persist after a reboot?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- run Clear-AzureRmContext
- open a new session
- login again using Connect-AzureRmAccount